# Best way to set up dynamic table in django tables2 (eg Meta class)

Tags: html, css, django, django-tables2

*Preface: I think I might be missing a more fundamental detail, but here goes...*

I am generating a table (https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with an dynamic column count which is leading to issues with column width needs when we end up with a table with many columns.  My users want certain columns to be wider than others, without losing any of the text in other columns to overflow.  It *is* ok to blow the table past 100% width (eg 1500px).

I can't use `style='table-width:auto'` since this doesn't respect specific column widths I set.  I CAN use `'table-width:fixed;width:$WIDTH'`, but I don't now the width soon enough to define it in the Meta class (or do I?).

What I feel like I might need to do is something like this?  I realize that Meta is not really supposed to work this way.

```
class ExampleTable(tables.Table):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_name_columns = self.get_total_name_columns()
        self.table_width = 500 + (120 * self.total_name_columns)
        super(ExampleTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
       # How would the value be dynamic like this?
       attrs = {'class': 'paleblue',  'style':'table-layout:fixed;width:%spx;' % (self.table_width) }
```

I thought another option might be to send that `self.table_width` value somewhere into the template and the use JS to resize the table after we load the page, but thought I would ask to see if other have experience with other solutions first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after posting the question I found one option.  If you wrap the column data in a `<div style="width:200px">Column Text</div>`, `table-layout:auto` will respect that.  So you can have the browser size all your columns automatically except the ones with divs wrapping the data.  Not quite what I was asking for above, but does work.